# Run equivalent batch file commands from python code

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd, intel-fortran

I have this batch file (abaqusjob.bat):

```
@echo off
@call ifortvars.bat intel64
cd c:\ABAQUS_Jobs
abaqus job=Australian2g1065fmpc user=routinem2mpc8f8el cpus=8 gpus=1 interactive
```

I'd like to run it from equivalent python code, using `Popen` for example, rather than running the batch file itself because I want to change some parameters in the last line automatically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually wrap my calls in a function similar to this one:

```
def issue_command(command):
    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    return process.communicate()
```

Then you can call the function like so:

```
stdout, stderr = issue_command("c:\ABAQUS_Jobs\abaqusjob.bat job=...")
```

There are however security concerns about using shell=True with untrusted input (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) which doesn't seem to apply to your question, but you didn't say where you are getting the data for the different set of arguments.

If you don't use "shell=True" then you must be explicit about paths and a few other things (see the paragraph above the warning in the link above).

You may also want to consider using a more sophisticated function along these lines

```
def issue_command(*args):
    process = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    return process.communicate()
```

which would be called like this:

```
stdout, stderr = issue_command("c:\ABAQUS_Jobs\abaqusjob.bat", "job=Australian2g1065fmpc", "user=routinem2mpc8f8el")
```

The benefits of using a signature like this can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

EDIT:
Since you said that either way is fine I will choose to use the batch script because I don't know what kind of environment you are setting up with "ifortvars.bat". So for parameters in batch script you use %n where n is the index of the argument. Thus:

```
@echo off
@call ifortvars.bat intel64
cd c:\ABAQUS_Jobs
abaqus job=%1 user=%2 cpus=%3 gpus=%4 interactive
```

would allow you to specify the job, user, cpus and gpus respectively. Then it's easy to call this in python using the function described above.

```
def issue_command(*args):
    process = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    return process.communicate()

args = [["c:\ABAQUS_Jobs\abaqusjob.bat", "Australian2fmpc", "routinem2", "8", "1"],
        ["c:\ABAQUS_Jobs\abaqusjob.bat", "Australian3fmpc", "routinem3", "4", "2"],
        ["c:\ABAQUS_Jobs\abaqusjob.bat", "Australian4fmpc", "routinem4", "5", "3"]]

for arg in args:
    out, err = issue_command(*arg)
```

I think that should solve your problem, but I am on my tablet right now, so if there is a mistake let me know below and I will fix it as soon as I can. Also your new requirement, should be easy enough as long as your python installation updated your registry (which it should have) all you should have to do is double click the .py file and it should run and close the cmd prompt when done. If that doesn't do it you should search google on how to set up file associations.

NOTE: Those values are samples and should be replaced with the arguments you wish to use. You also may want to change what is parametrized in your batch script like I said this was an example.

Comment: Thanks! I just have a question: when you write `issue_command("c:\ABAQUS_Jobs\abaqusjob.bat job=...")` you are asking the system to run the bat file and then the abaqus command? If yes, I don't understand what it does, because running the bat file would run everything in a single go (so no need of writing the abaqus line?). Hope my question is clear to you.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. You said you want to run the command by changing the parameters on the last line so I kind of assumed you would parameterize the last line. Do you want to translate your batch script to python or do you want to alter your batch script to accept parameters so you could then repeatedly call your batch script with different parameters. When you answer I will update answer to include what you want.

Comment: Either way is ok for me. I have no preference. As an additional requirement I just need for the cmd window to close after the command is completed. This is what happens with my batch file as it is. What it would be nice is that I could change for instance the `cpus` number or the `job` name within python. Then it is indifferent for me if either the bat file is changed accordingly or all commands are ran within python (although the latter is my question). Thanks!!!

Comment: did this new edit work for you? If so you might consider accepting the answer and if not I will be more than happy to help again.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I couldn't get it to work. I used `args = [["C:\Users\jandre\Desktop\rel2.bat", "A2", "routinem2mpc8f8el", "8", "1"]]` and When I print `err` I get ` 'C:\Users\jandre\Desktopel2.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` which I do not understand why it gives this error since `Desktopel2.bat` is not passed into the bat file. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: \r is an escape sequence meaning a carriage return. This is present in your firs argument. To get around this you can either use "C:\Users\jandre\Desktop\\rel2.bat" or use the pythonic version os.path.join("C:", "Users", "jandre", "Desktop", "rel2.bat") which will handle all of the escaping and cross platform issues for you.

Comment: I just have another thing I'd like to ask you. How can I make the command window show when running the bat file? I couldn't get it to show up. All things run at the background. Thanks once again!